# What is the purpose of skew pickups?

Tags: pick-ups

I sometimes see electric guitars where one of the pickups are not in line with the bridge. What is the purpose of this? Seems to be a thing with strat bridge pickups.

What purpose does this serve?

[image: Example]

Comment: My guess is a desire to either enhance or reduce certain  high-frequency overtones.  As a totally unsubstantiated example: the layout you see will be sensitive to overtones on the top strings, emphazising the peak notes, while the overtones on the bass strings are reduced, producing a "cleaner" bass.

Comment: Difficult to do with humbuckers, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/why-is-the-bridge-pickup-on-a-stratocaster-angled), it is as the commentor suggested; this angle produces brighter highs and reduced bass.

"The closer you are to the bridge, the more 'trebly' the sound".